# Subscript and Superscript Characters in Cargo Doc?

Tags: rust

I looked up how to generate subscripts and superscripts on `cargo doc`, but I was not able to tell if it exists. I want to do it within the code, not in a standalone Markdown file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with html `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags:

```rust
/// x<sup>y</sup><sub>z</sub>
```

will produce:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use UTF-8 or HTML `<sub>` and `<sup>`:

```rust
/// Subscript and Superscript Characters in rustdoc
///
/// Using UTF-8: ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁼ₐ₉ (doesn't have all letters)
///
/// Using HTML: <sub>0123456789 works with letters to</sub> <sup>0123456789 works with letters to</sup>
pub fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

renders as

[image: example]

Wikipedia [has a list of available Unicode subscripts and superscripts characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).